# Jekyll agenda thing in a table

Tags: jekyll

I am working on a Jekyll website which needs an agenda. I would like to add points to the agenda in my `_config.yml` file so it looks like this in the file.

```
agenda:
 date: 26 January
 thing: Birthday
 date: 30 March
 thing: Another birthday
```

Another option would be:

```
agenda:
 item: <td> Date </td> <td> Thing </td>
 item: <td> Date </td> <td> Thing </td>
```

As you can see above the output has to be a list. It does not work no matter what I try. This is the last thing I have tried.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
   {% for point in site.agenda %}
    <tr>
      {{ point }}
    </tr>
      {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I hope you can help me solve this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't try this right now, but what about:

```
agenda:
 - date: January 26
   event: Birthday
 - date: May 30
   event: Another birthday

Note: (make sure that the - is indented by at least one space and that indents match)
```

And then:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    {% for point in site.agenda %}<tr>
      <td>{{ point.date }}</td><td>{{ point.event }}</td>
    </tr>{% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Or something quite similar. In one page, I have an alternative syntax:

```
agenda:
 - { date: January 26, event: Birthday }

etc...
```

That works like a treat.